# Linux Mint, sudo apt-get update 404 errors,

Tags: linux

I am using the latest Linux Mint and have tried many solutions, but I need a solution that is directly applicable to this problem.

*All https:// have been removed to prevent spam.*

W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/shnatsel/zram/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/shnatsel/zram/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/shnatsel/zram/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'll agree that you probably need to reset your software sources. If you need some help on how to do that, here are some instructions that *should* work for Linux Mint (and Ubuntu too, they're very silmiar).

### Backup the sources.list files

Just copy them to a backup folder somewhere, this should work:

`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old`
`sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d.old`

or put the copy in your home somewhere:

`sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list* /home/myuser/`

### Restoring the default `sources.list` & `sources.list.d` files

If you do this it should generate a new fresh `sources.list` file

1. delete the old files:

   `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list`

   and

   `sudo rm -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
2. Then Run "Software Sources" from the programs menu / dash, or in a terminal

   `sudo software-sources`

   and select/check-mark backports/romeo if desired, pick servers or keep the defaults, and update.

**OR** this is what a default Linux Mint 17.2  file *should currently* look like, with backported packages selected:

```
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela main upstream import backport  #id:linuxmint_main
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela main #id:linuxmint_extra

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
```

- The site http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ has a LOT of optional PPA's too, looks quite useful.  [courtesy https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories ]

[Credit to one of my answers on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569149/cant-install-anytime-in-ubuntu/569647#569647)

Comment: Running software-sources gives me the error:
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d'
Which makes sense, since I deleted it, but software-sources does not create a new one? I am on 18.3

Comment: @eddy147 It used to work, back when I last tried it. Does recreating the empty directory then work ok?  `sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d` should do it

Answer (score 1):

All of the Linux Mint 17 releases - Quiana, Rebecca, Rafaela and Rosa - are based on Ubuntu 14.04 and packages compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 are not available from ppa:shnatsel/zram. That is why you are getting `Failed to fetch ... 404 Not Found` errors when trying to update your software.

To remove these errors you must remove ppa:shnatsel/zram from your software sources. Your software sources are determined by this file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The easiest way to edit the sources.list file is from the terminal  in nano editor using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The instructions for using nano are always displayed at the bottom of the page. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem (Linux Mint 18.1), but updating with the graphical update manager. In my case the "Failed to fetch ....404 Not Found" was solved when I went (in the graphical Update Manager) to Edit -> Software Sources -> Maintanence. 
There, click "Fix MergeList problems" and click on the "Update the cache" button. After this action I was able to update everything without errors.